# Why can't Laravel 4 see my testing config in the apps/config folder?

Tags: sqlite, laravel-4, phpunit

I have followed the tutorial here, but any database connection is still hitting my primary development database locally.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models--net-30087

Under app/config/testing I have defined database.php as per this tutorial and still it isn't connecting properly.

```
<?php
return array(
    'default' => 'sqlite',
    'connections' => array(
        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ),
    )
);
```

My bootstrap/start.php is as follows:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('macbook'),
));
```

According to everything I have read, Laravel should be able to define its own testing environment.

TIA.

Comment: How are you running the test? Can you post your test code?

Comment: I am just using the defaulted example in place with some additional code that creates a record in the database so I can see if it is still talking to the wrong one.

    
    class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
      public function testBasicExample()
      {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
      }
    }

Then executing from the project root with vendor/bin/phpunit.


Sorry for edit, can't seem to get the formatting for code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you havent rebuilt the autoloader classmap.

Try doing this in the terminal:

composer dump-autoload

Comment: No dice.  I have thrown some checks into the output to see the result and it is still showing I am in the testing environment but using mysql not sqllite.

.************************testing************************mysql